# Relationship between GEF and GMF?

Tags: java, eclipse, modeling, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I'm working on summary on the eclipse modeling project and its various sub - projects. It is not going to get published, it's sole purpose is to help my colleagues and above all my boss to get an overall impression of the topic.

For better understanding I took a diagram from the eclipse GEF User Guide and modified it. I want to show the Relationship between GEF (Graphical Editing Framework) and GMF (Graphical Modeling Framework). Did i get this right?

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you did not get it right, at least it's difficult to understand the diagram.

I guess it should look something like that:

```
      GMF
     /   \
  EMF     GEF
           \
           Draw2D
```

Generated GMF-Source makes use of EMF to handle the model's data, and GEF to display/edit it.

Have a look at
[Introducing the GMF Runtime](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Introducing-GMF/article.html) (Components)

Comment: Peter, it is not a hierarchy, but from a "usage" perspective or "depends" then yes, you have it right, eclipse docs in the online help explain this sufficiently, I read them at one point. +1

Answer (score 1):

In your diagram isn't easy to understand the role of GMF. I don't work with GMF for some time, but if I remember, GMF provides code generation and a framework. This framework uses GEF and EMF and does most of the heavy work involved in a model editor. It probably can be seen as a new layer over GEF and EMF. Maybe you can change it to show these relations.

You may also consider showing the workflow involved in the development of a GMF editor

Answer (score 1):

You asked for the workflow involved in the development of a GMF editor. I Hope the following information will be helpful to you.

There are 6 models that you need to develop in order to generate a graphical editor:

- Domain model
- Domain gen model
- Tooling definition model
- Graphical definition model
- Mapping definition model
- Diagram editor gen model

generate the diagram code.

There are many options to develop your domain model (XML schema, annotated java,...). Eclipse GMF provides wizards to create all these models and you can configure settings to get what you want.

After creating these models, you just need to run the project to get your editor!!